# IE Edge Hmmm...can’t reach this page

Tags: iframe, microsoft-edge

Hi am added iFrame on my site to access other site, it is working both Chrome and IE 11 but it is not working in IE Edge, see error below:

[image]

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the Network tab saying?

Comment: Opening ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/dnserror.html

Comment: You could be a victim of Edge's buggy CORS implementation